# Solve the ODE $y' = \lambda (y^d - 1)$ on $[0,\tau), \tau <1$, with $y(0) = \lambda$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, hypergeometric-function

## Question

Let $\lambda \in (0,1)$ and $d \in \{ 2,3,\dots \}$. Now consider the ODE:
$$
y' = \lambda (y^d - 1) \mbox{ with } y(0) = \lambda,
$$
which I would like to solve.

## Thoughts

I can simply write this equation as:
$$
\frac{dy}{y^d - 1} = \lambda dx,
$$
integrating both parts of the equation yields:
$$
\int_0^\tau \frac{1}{y^d-1} dy = \lambda x + C,
$$
but the integral on the left equals:
$$
-y \cdot _2F_1\left(1,\frac{1}{d};1+\frac{1}{d};y^d\right),
$$
but I don't really see how to invert this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial condition is $x=0,y=\lambda$, so your integration limits should reflect this

$$ \lambda x = \int_\lambda^y \frac{1}{t^d-1} dt $$

The integral is elementary for integer values of $d$, since the denominator can always be factored as $(t-1)P_{d-1}(t)$ where $P_{d-1}$ is some polynomial with degree $d-1$. What you have up there is just a general form.

The exact solution will depend on the specific value of $d$. For example, when $d=2$ we have

$$ \lambda x = \frac{1}{2}\ln \left(\frac{1-y}{1+y} \right) - \frac{1}{2}\ln \left(\frac{1-\lambda}{1+\lambda}\right) $$

which is equivalent to
$$ y(x) = \frac{(1+\lambda)-(1-\lambda)e^{2\lambda x}}{(1+\lambda)+(1-\lambda)e^{2\lambda x}} $$

From $d=3$ onwards, the integral becomes more and more complicated, and an explicit solution may not exist. In general it's bounded in $|y| < 1$ due to the pole in the integrand. Furthermore, in the interval $[0,1]$, $|y| \le \lambda$